# How to change view from one component by clicking a button from another component using angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding

I'm new to AngularJs and need help.
I have two components (welcome and chat) in index.html and two test buttons that toggle them between each other.

```
 <div ng-switch on ='view'>
    <button ng-click='view="welcome"'>Welcome</button>
    <button ng-click='view="chat"'>Chat</button>
    <welcome ng-switch-when='welcome' ></welcome>
    <chat ng-switch-when='chat'></chat>
    
  </div>
```

The "Welcome.html" has a `<button>Start chat</button>`.
How to transfer the behavior of the test `<button ng-click='view="chat"'>Chat</button>`in index.html
to the `<button class="start-chat-button" ng-click="view='chat'">Start chat</button>`in welcome.html? Now this button doesn't switch the views.

Code for ng-switch:

```
    angular.module('myApp', [
      'ngRoute',
      'myApp.welcome',
      'myApp.chat',
      'myApp.version'
    ])
    .controller('View', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.view = 'welcome';
    }]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side question, are you learning AngularJS because you must maintain an old project and you have no choice? Or are you simply learning it "for fun", to get skilled at it? Because if it's the latter, you have to know AngularJS started dying when Angular 2 was released, about 5 years ago

Comment: @JeremyThille, I'm learning AngularJs because this is my employer's will. Now I am an intern in a large company in my city and the result of my internship should be an application in Angularjs.

Comment: So it'll be in order to maintain existing applications. I doubt you will develop any new application using a technology that got deprecated in 2016. I haven't touched it since then, so I don't know ho to answer your question. I used to know...

Comment: @JeremyThille maybe... think you're right and I'll maintain existing project.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer wasn't as difficult as I waited for)

Bindings resolved the problem! Thanks to the article https://blog.krawaller.se/posts/dissecting-bindings-in-angularjs/

welcome.html:

```
<welcome>
  <button ng-click="changeToChat()">Start chat</button>
</welcome>
```

welcome.js:

```
.directive('welcome', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        changeToChat: '<' //the most important thing!
}
```

index.html:

```
<welcome change-to-chat="showChat"></welcome> //look to this attribute
```

app.js:

```
$scope.showChat = function() {
      $scope.isWelcome = !$scope.isWelcome;
  };
```

I wrote a function showChat in app.js. Then passed it as a callback to welcome's directive scope. That's all! And button changes views from welcome to chat.